# Applying Metrics in a Quarkus app for MongoDB connection

Tags: mongodb, connection, screen-scraping, quarkus, metrics

At the moment I am trying to apply the following how-to to my Quarkus app: [MongoDB Metrics](https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb#metrics)

So I have added the `quarkus-smallrye-metrics` and `quarkus-mongodb-client` dependencies in the pom.xml and added `quarkus.mongodb.metrics.enabled=true` to the `application.properties`.

When I run the service, and go to [/q/metrics](http://localhost:8080/q/metrics), unfortunately specific MongoDB metrics will not appear. Generic `vendor` items but not related to MongoDB.
Even if I put the `quarkus.mongodb.metrics.enabled` to `=false`, it did not changed because `vendor` still appears.

How can I configure the Metrics of de Quarkus App for MongoDB so I can read the MongoDB metrics of the app?

Comment: Have you tried using `quarkus-micrometer` instead of `quarkus-smallrye-metrics`?

Comment: @geoand yes I have, unfortunatelly the `vendor` items will not appear so in the how-to, it is false to say that it is possible to use `quarkus-micrometer`

Comment: @geoand EDIT: if I use `quarkus-micrometer`, unfortunately the [/q/metrics](http://localhost:8080/q/metrics) won't work at all

Comment: Then something must be configured incorrectly. See https://quarkus.io/guides/micrometer

Comment: @geoand if you try this [mongo-metrics](https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb#metrics):
1. if you implement `quarkus-micrometer` [/q/metrics](http://localhost:8080/q/metrics) wont work
2. if you implement `quarkus-smallrye-metrics`, you cannot use it with the `micrometer` dependency
3. if you use `quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus` then it works